# How to make text animate (slide down) with div using .slidedown()

Tags: jquery, animation, slide, easing

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is having the navigation bar on my site drop down when a certain anchor point is reached. I can't seem to figure out how to get the text to animate (drop down) with the div. The text is stationary and the drop down effect just uncovers it.

Is there a way to have the text move using .slidedown() or do I need to incorporate .animate() to accomplish this? I have tried using the .animate(), but I couldn't figure out how to hide and unhide the div with it. If any one has any suggestions or can  point me in the right direction, It will be much appreciated.

```js
var t = $("#about").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= t ) {
        $('#global-nav').slideDown(500, 'easeOutBounce');
    } else {
        $('#global-nav').slideUp(500, 'easeInExpo');
    }  
});
```

```css
html { height: 2000px; } 

#global-nav {
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    color:#fff;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
}
#global-nav p {
    margin-top:15px;
}
#about{
   margin-top:400px;
```

```html
<div id="global-nav"><p>Random Text</p>.</div>

<div id="about"></div>
```

This is what I have working so far : http://jsfiddle.net/Hysteresis/0oazqj4y/36/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the nature of `fixed` elements and how the child elements behave inside them. Since `slideDown` is animating the height of the element, the `p` lives inside the `fixed` element - it's not going to have any effect.

Try adding `display:none;` to the `p` CSS, and:

```
$('#global-nav p').slideDown(500, 'easeOutBounce');
```

to your JS

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0oazqj4y/38/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about the fixed elements.  Still pretty new to all this. That will work! Thanks for your help!